# Asymmetrical CSS Shadow

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to create a shadow like this:

[image]

What I want is shadow that is bigger on the bottom-center than on the bottom-left/right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely can, use pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` to achieve it: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GZCw/1/))

```css
.effect{
    position:relative;
}

.effect:before, .effect:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top:50%;
    bottom:0;
    left:10px; /* distance from left inwards */
    right:10px; /* distance from right inwards */
    -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
    border-radius:100px / 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it has shadow on the left and the right side of the box and I don't want that. Only on the bottom. ( http://jsfiddle.net/4GZCw/ ) Do you know how to fix that ?

Comment: I've added [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GZCw/1/) to my answer - take a look at the `left` and `right` of the pseudo elements. made them bigger.. you can play with them to get perfectly what you want. you can also reduce the `20px` of the `box-shadow`

Comment: I think this is an unnecessary use of pseudo elements. Just my two cents. :)

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/PtbNb/1/

```
<div class="box"></div>

.box {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 32px 24px -28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: -10px 32px 24px -28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: -10px 32px 24px -28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    background:grey;
}
```

Generator: http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow